# What happened to DigestRealmBase in Glassfish 4.0?

Tags: java, java-ee-6, glassfish-3, glassfish-4, java-ee-7

I successfully integrated my custom security realm in Glassfish 3.1.2.2 and it worked just fine. Now I am trying to port my project from GF3 to the newly released Glassfish 4.0.

But I now get the following error when trying to configure my custom realm in GF4:

```
Exception while running a command java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/enterprise/security/ee/auth/realm/DigestRealmBase
```

Does somebody know if the class "DigestRealmBase" has changed it's location ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nothing change for that class with GF4. 
It is still in package com.sun.enterprise.security.ee.auth.realm. 
You will find the class file in the jar **modules/security-ee.jar**.

Regards,

Mickaël

Comment: Thanks for the info. I have slightly rewritten the realm and it now extends from AppservRealm instead of DigestRealmBase. But now ProgrammaticLogin on the stand-alone client side doesn't work anymore. Do you know how to programmatically log in with AppservRealm on stand-alone clients?

Comment: Allright I found it :-) it's also in security-ee.jar, com.sun.enterprise.security.ee.auth.login.ProgrammaticLogin